# How can Jetpack Compose Navigation remember multiple back stacks?

Tags: jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm reading about Navigation in Jetpack Compose, and found this example I don't understand.

From [the docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav):

> By using the `saveState` and `restoreState` flags, the state *and back stack* of that item is correctly saved and restored as you swap between bottom navigation items.

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
Scaffold(
  bottomBar = {
    BottomNavigation {
      val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
      val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
      items.forEach { screen ->
        BottomNavigationItem(
          icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
          label = { Text(stringResource(screen.resourceId)) },
          selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true,
          onClick = {
            navController.navigate(screen.route) {
              // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
              // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
              // on the back stack as users select items
              popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                saveState = true
              }
              // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
              // reselecting the same item
              launchSingleTop = true
              // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
              restoreState = true
            }
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
) { innerPadding ->
  NavHost(navController, startDestination = Screen.Profile.route, Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
    composable(Screen.Profile.route) { Profile(navController) }
    composable(Screen.FriendsList.route) { FriendsList(navController) }
  }
}
```

Specifically, I don't understand how the back stack can be saved if clicking an item in the bottom bar pops the navigation stack [to the root](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavGraph.Companion#(androidx.navigation.NavGraph).findStartDestination()).

I would imagine a journey like:

1. User moves to `/FriendsList/Friend(A)/Friend(B)/Friend(C)`
2. User clicks `Profile` button, resetting the navigation stack to `/Profile`
3. User clicks `FriendsList` button.

Based on the explanation, I would expect the navigation stack to be re-set to `/FriendsList/FriendA/FriendB/FriendC`, even though the `onClick` listener seems to set the stack to `/FriendsList`?

I really don't understand how this can happen, how does the navigation controller link the route to the entire navigation sub-stack? Is `item.route` changing state containing the full route to `/FriendsList/Friend(A)/Friend(B)/Friend(C)`, or is something else going on? Or do I understand the example wrong?

I suspect maybe the underlying mechanism is that `FriendsList` contains a nested navigation graph, since the example doesn't actually show any `Friend` route definitions. The state of this entire nested graph is contained somehow, i.e., something like `/FriendsList{FriendA/FriendB/FriendC}`, and a move to `/FriendsList` will unpack this navigation stack. Is that kind of how it works?

Answer (score 4):

The code in the example you gave has only 1 navHost and 1 navController so it is not possible to save the FriendList back stack seperated from the rest back stack.
To achive this behavior you need to declare nested navHosts. Each of them with his own navController and thats it. All the rest is working automatically.

Here is an example

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination

Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        BottomNavigation {
            items.forEach { screen ->
                BottomNavigationItem(
                    icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
                    label = { Text(stringResource(screen.resourceId)) },
                    selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true,
                    onClick = {
                        navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                            // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
                            // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
                            // on the back stack as users select items
                            popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                saveState = true
                            }
                            // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
                            // reselecting the same item
                            launchSingleTop = true
                            // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
                            restoreState = true
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
) { innerPadding ->

    NavHost(
        navController,
        startDestination = Screen.ProfileNavHost.route,
        Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
    ) {

        composable(Screen.ProfileNavHost.route) {
            val profileNavController = rememberNavController()
            NavHost(
                navController = profileNavController,
                startDestination = Screen.ProfileRoot.route
            ) {
                composable(Screen.ProfileRoot.route) {
                    ProfileRoot(navController)
                }
                composable(Screen.ProfileScreen.route) {
                    ProfileScreen(navController)
                }
            }
        }

        composable(Screen.FriendsListNavHost.route) {
            val friendsListNavController = rememberNavController()
            NavHost(
                navController = friendsListNavController,
                startDestination = Screen.FriendsListRoot.route
            ) {
                composable(Screen.FriendsListRoot.route) {
                    FriendsList(navController)
                }
                composable(Screen.FriendsListFriend.route) {
                    FriendsListFriend(navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Took me ages to find this, thanks for leaving this here!

Comment: Hey @vasberc, -theoratically speaking- in this case, is this possible to navigate profileStack's screen3 to friendListStack's screen5 for example ?

Comment: I am not so experienced in jetpack compose, but I can tell you the logic of how I have done this with the views. To make this navigation you have to change the selected item of the bottom navigation menu by making a navigation with the top navController. Then you need to do the navigation to screen5 with the navController of the friendList navHost.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've set it up: there's nested navigation with distinct paths for both authentication and main navigation. The main navigation also includes multiple backstacks.

Starting with the Bottom navigation setup:

```
@Composable
fun BottomBar(
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    val navigationScreen = listOf(
        AppScreen.Main.Home, AppScreen.Main.Notification, AppScreen.Main.Profile
    )

    NavigationBar {

        val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route

        navigationScreen.forEach { item ->

            NavigationBarItem(
                selected = currentRoute == item.route,

                label = {
                    Text(text = stringResource(id = item.title!!), style = MaterialTheme.typography.displaySmall)
                },
                icon = {
//                    BadgedBox(badge = {}) {
//
//                    }
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = (if (item.route == currentRoute) item.selectedIcon else item.unselectedIcon)!!,
                        contentDescription = stringResource(id = item.title!!)
                    )
                },

                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(item.route) {
                        popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                            saveState = true
                        }
                        launchSingleTop = true
                        restoreState = true
                    }
                },
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**AuthNavGraph.kt**

> It handles the first navigation graph destinations with its own
> navController.

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.authNavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
  
    navigation(
        startDestination = AppScreen.Auth.Login.route,
        route = AppScreen.Auth.route
    ) {
        composable(route = AppScreen.Auth.Login.route) {
            LoginScreen(
                navigateToHome = {
                    navController.navigate(AppScreen.Main.route) {
                        popUpTo(AppScreen.Auth.route) {
                            inclusive = true
                        }
                    }
                },
                navigateToSignUp = {
                    navController.navigate(AppScreen.Auth.Register.route)
                },
            )
        }

        composable(route = AppScreen.Auth.Register.route) {
            SignUpScreen(onNavigateBack = {
                navController.navigateUp()
            })
        }
    }

}
```

ChildNavHost.kt,

> It includes all the backstack navigation hosts required for BottomAppBar.

```
    --- Home Nav Host
    
    @Composable
    fun HomeNavHost() {
      
        val homeNavController = rememberNavController()
        NavHost(navController = homeNavController, startDestination = AppScreen.Main.Home.route){
    
            composable(
                route = AppScreen.Main.Home.route) {
                HomeScreen(onProductClick = {
                    val route = AppScreen.Main.ProductDetail.createRoute(productId = it)
                    AppLog.showLog("Router---> $route")
                    homeNavController.navigate(route)
                })
            }
    
            composable(route = AppScreen.Main.ProductDetail.route) {
                ProductDetail() {
                    homeNavController.navigateUp()
                }
            }
    
        }
    
    }
    
    --- Profile Nav Host
    
    @Composable
    fun ProfileNavHost(rootNavController: NavHostController) {
        val profileNavController = rememberNavController()
    
        NavHost(navController = profileNavController, startDestination = AppScreen.Main.Profile.route) {
    
            composable(
                route = AppScreen.Main.Profile.route
            ) {
                ProfileScreen(navigateToLogin = {
                    rootNavController.navigate(AppScreen.Auth.route) {
                        popUpTo(AppScreen.Main.route) {
                            inclusive = true
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
    
        }
    
    }

--- Notification Nav Host

fun NotificationNavHost() {
    val profileNavController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = profileNavController, startDestination = AppScreen.Main.Notification.route){

        composable(
            route = AppScreen.Main.Notification.route
        ) {
            NotificationScreen()
        }

    }

}
```

The main Nav Graph Looks like the below:

> It handles all the main navigation destinations.

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.mainNavGraph(rootNavController: NavHostController) {
      
        navigation(
            route = AppScreen.Main.route,
            startDestination = AppScreen.Main.Home.route
        ) {
    
            composable(route = AppScreen.Main.Home.route) {
                HomeNavHost()
            }
    
            composable(route = AppScreen.Main.Notification.route) {
                NotificationNavHost()
            }
    
            composable(route = AppScreen.Main.Profile.route) {
                ProfileNavHost(rootNavController)
            }
    
        }
    
    }
```

Root navigation graph as below:

> It includes all the nested graph respective to the NavHost.

```
@Composable
fun RootNavHost(isLoggedIn: Boolean, rootNavHostController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = rootNavHostController,
        startDestination = if(isLoggedIn) AppScreen.Main.route else AppScreen.Auth.route
    ) {

        authNavGraph(rootNavHostController)
        mainNavGraph(rootNavHostController)
    }
}
```

And Finally in MainActivity.kt

```
...
  Scaffold(
                    snackbarHost = {
                        SnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState)
                    },
                    bottomBar = {
                        if (bottomBarState.value) {
                            BottomBar(navController = navController)
                        }
                    }) { paddingValues ->
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)
                    ) {

                        // For multiple back stack nav host
                        RootkNavHost(
                            isAuthenticated,
                            rootNavHostController = navController
                        )
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Feel free to drop a comment with any suggestions; I'm uncertain if it's the optimal approach, but it's functioning effectively.